# Jar files just wont run

Tags: java, jar

A couple of days ago i installed the latest Java update. in the process i believe something may have gone wrong, as now when i try to open a jar file  (double clicking it) it just pops up a terminal window which displays something like:

```
Cannot find main class "..."
```

However, if i try to run it straight from the terminal with:

```
java -jar foo.jar
```

it will run fine. I have tried doing a full re- install of the JRE and JDK, just for good measure but this has had no effect. Has anyone got any recommendations?

I am using Windows XP with Java 7 update 7.

Comment: What OS are you using. Also this is probably a question for Super User (I think?)

Comment: It maybe that your enviornment got screwed up when you installed a new version of java. Check your path and your classpath to make sure neither contains a reference to the old directories.

Comment: I just tried re- setting my environment, but i think i may have done it wrong, i set it up like: 

Variable Name: PATH
Variable value: G:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;G:\WINDOWS\system32\;G:\WINDOWS\;G:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\

Comment: classpath is more important, if java runs without a path, path is setup.  Make sure that the jar files that in the same dir as your jar are all listed in there with full path (use " if the path includes a space).  As well as the javaqt.jar (with the correct path)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First type `java -version` from your command prompt, if this command displays the installed JDK version, then you JDK path is perfectly fine.

**2.** Secondly Perhaps your file associations got messed up. At the command prompt, try running

`ftype | find "jarfile"`

`On my 64-bit Windows 7 computer, that shows`

`jarfile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*`

**You can also change it with ftype:**

`ftype jarfile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*`

Also of note was the fact that the application install could be doing a silent install of the JRE, which (silently, of course!) does not associate .jar files correctly. So you have to change the main program install to no longer do a silent install, and also clean up the file associations. After reinstalling the JRE, you could execute the .jar file by double-clicking on it

Comment: java -version
returns correctly
and the
    ftype | "jarfile" 
returns the same as what yours did (minus the (x86)), and i have already tried re- installing everything. twice.

Comment: Have u reinstalled the JRE ?? and Making the program not to be installed silently ??

Comment: Oh, sorry i got confused by that, is it an option on the installer or something?

Comment: i hope this link will provide some pointers http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jre-installer-options.html